# Pandas pivot table using sum(min_count=1) in pandas 0.22

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am migrating my code to Pandas 0.22 and running into a problem with a pivot table.
In  version 0.20 I have a line of code. This has the behaviour that when the cell in the pivot table is empty the sum aggregation returns NAN.

```
workload_pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(workload_df, index=["athlete_id", "date"], values=["workload"], columns=["type"], aggfunc=('sum','last'))
```

However due to the change in Pandas 0.22 sum now returns 0 when no data is found. The documentation says that you can pass min_count=1 as an argument to get the original behaviour https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html. However I can not get this to work in the pivot table.

Comment: Can you provide some minimal data where you find this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lambda` function and for same column name use `tuple` - first value is new column name and second aggregate function:

```
tup = ('sum', lambda x: x.sum(min_count=1))
workload_pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(workload_df, index=["athlete_id", "date"], 
                                    values=["workload"], 
                                    columns=["type"], aggfunc=(tup,'last'))
```

**Sample**:

```
workload_df = pd.DataFrame({'athlete_id':list('aaabbb'),
                   'date':pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01'] * 3 + ['2015-01-01'] * 3),
                   'workload':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,2,3],
                   'type':list('aaaabb')})

print (workload_df)
  athlete_id       date type  workload
0          a 2015-01-01    a       NaN
1          a 2015-01-01    a       NaN
2          a 2015-01-01    a       NaN
3          b 2015-01-01    a       4.0
4          b 2015-01-01    b       2.0
5          b 2015-01-01    b       3.0
```

---

```
workload_pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(workload_df, index=["athlete_id", "date"], 
                                    values=["workload"], 
                                    columns=["type"], aggfunc=('sum','last'))

print (workload_pivot_df)
                      workload               
                          last       sum     
type                         a    b    a    b
athlete_id date                              
a          2015-01-01      NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN #<-all NaNs created 0.0
b          2015-01-01      4.0  3.0  4.0  5.0


tup = ('sum', lambda x: x.sum(min_count=1))
workload_pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(workload_df, index=["athlete_id", "date"], 
                                    values=["workload"], 
                                    columns=["type"], aggfunc=(tup,'last'))

print (workload_pivot_df)
                      workload               
                          last       sum     
type                         a    b    a    b
athlete_id date                              
a          2015-01-01      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN #<-back compatible need NaN
b          2015-01-01      4.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
```

Comment: @warwickh - Glad can help!